# Design trailing stop column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I created a dataframe with pandas and calculated the percentage of earning or losing:
and I hope I can design 2 column like entered market and trail for a trailing stop backtest for example 5% like:

```
earning/losing    entered market        trail
             0                 0            0
             1                 1            1
             2                 1            2
             3                 1            3
             7                 1            7
             4                 1            7
             5                 1            7
             8                 1            8
             2                 0            0
             5                 0            0
             4                 0            0
```

I had tried using numpy condition to create like but I can't complete
the rest of condition:

```
condition = [(df['earning/losing'] > 0) & (df['earning/losing'] >df['earning/losing'].shift(-1)) & (df['earning/losing'] - df['earning/losing'].shift(-1) < 5),]
value = [df.earning/losing,]
df['trail'] = np.select(condition,value,default = 0)
```

I think if I could create a column like trail, then I can judge the trailing condition,

But I dont know how to create the trail column in pandas

can anyone help me out? thanks alot!

Comment: How do you calculate `entered market` and `trail` column? What is the logic used here? Please edit your question with more details.

Comment: I just can't , the only column I can create is earning/losing column, I tried using numpy condition to create, but I can't determine to keep the highest value of earning/column in trail column.

Comment: But there must be some logic that you have used to create `entered market` and `trail` column, right? without knowing the actual logic its really not possible for anyone to help you properly. You have to edit your question with some details.

Comment: Yes, I edited, but it's unfinished, sorry for that. I dont know how to keep the highest value yet...